# Part of div transparent?

Tags: css, html, transparency

Is it possible to make only part of div transparent like an amount of space in div.

For example, you select 100px from top of div and the top 100px have an opacity set?

How would I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to do a gradient, or do you want to offset an image?  Or do you want a solid background color?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted when your problem is solved, that'll help you earn reputation here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a couple of things:

1. Try a background image where half is transparent and the other half is not.
2. Use a CSS gradient in such a way that half is transparent and the other is not. Ex:

   ```
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,0) 50%, rgba(34,125,203,1) 52%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   ```
3. Use multiple divs where one has transparent BG and the other does not. Ex:

   ```
   <div>
      <div id="transparent" style="background: transparent"></div>
      <div id="not-transparent" style="background: #000"></div>
   </div>
   ```

I'm sure there are other ways, but those are the first three that come to mind.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Either you create the right `background-image` using a semi-transparent PNG (transparent at top, opaque at bottom for example) ; either you use two sub-divs, each having its own `background-color` (one of which with rgba for the transparent part).

Answer (score 3):

You can use css3 properties along with pseudo elements to create this effect:

The trick is to draw a box with `:before` or `:after` pseudo element. We can apply `background` property for inner semi-transparent background. While for outer `background` we can use a large `box-shadow` value.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 120px;
  width: 250px;
}

.box:before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #000;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ff5a00 0, #ffae00 100%);
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 120px;
  width: 250px;
}

.box:before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #000;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I have used this answer with opacity+background instead of box-shadow and had good result